# Modal animation with jetpack navigation transition

Tags: android, android-animation, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

How can you create modal transition animation?

I'm using the jetpack navigation graph where you can bind transition animations. But the default behaviour looks really weird. Let me explain why.

If you bind an enter animation without an exit animation. Your exit fragment will disappear at the start of the animation. Which doesn't look really nice.

So i decided to create an exit animation with the same duration of the enter animation, which does nothing. But now the enter fragment will slide on top of the exit fragment but underneath the toolbar of the exit fragment (each fragment contains a toolbar).

Is there a way to create a good looking modal animation for a jetpack transition?

This is my slide up animation..

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true">
<translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0%">
</translate>
</set>
```

Comment: Which type of enter and exit animation. Do you want?

Comment: @HeisenBrg The enter animation should slide up from the bottom, while the exit animation should do nothing. Similar to the modal animation of iOS.

Comment: Can you share some code? Specifically, the part where you are setting the transitions to the fragments would be appreciated :)

Comment: @miguelarc i don't set any animation in code. I bind my animation by setting an app:enterAnim and app:exitAnim in my navGraph action. And to trigger the transition i call findNavController().navigate(R.id.my_action_id, bundle)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding from what you described, the FragmentB is being pushed on top of the FragmentA, but underneath the tooldbar, making it have 2 toolbars. Is that right? You are probably setting the action in a child resource. Perhaps you can set the action to a parent one, the one which adds the toolbar and the fragment. It's difficult to have a exact response, since we have no code to look at :) Check this and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanx for your answer, i'm not really sure of what part of my code you would like to see. Because all the binding is done by the single oneliner in my xml like i sad in my last comment. 
Each fragment has its own toolbar. Thats not the problem. The problem is that the fragment i navigate to slides over the exit fragment but underneath the old toolbar until the animation is done. When the animation is done the old fragment including the old toolbar disappears.  

For more information about jetpack:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing

Comment: I'm not using a toolbar, so I don't have the same issue as you. I just want to say your idea of setting the exit animation to be an animation which does nothing, with the same duration, helped me a lot.